# New-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy "not implemented" on Exchange 2007 SP3

Tags: powershell, exchange-2007

If I try to run:

```
New-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy Test
```

directly in the Powershell, it asks me if im sure, and if so, it does what it should. But if I try the same from my example Code in C#, then I get an error, saying that "the current host does not implement it". Other Commands like Set-CASMailbox or Get-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy work just fine, both in the powershell and my application.

The Exchange Server/Windows Server 2008R2 and Domain are all setup completely new (test-environment). Is there a way to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot more research, trial-and-error and work, I found that not the "New-ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy" feature that is not implemented, but the "ask the user if he is sure" feature. I must have overlooked the parameter for that, but it is possible to turn of this by setting "Confirm" to false. Doing so, everything works as expected.